# How can I implement my custom toolbar in my Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I read so much article and watched so many videos but I still don't know, how to set up an action bar in an Fragment. I have a activity X with an custom toolbar and one navigation view on the top left(the toolbar is separated in an xml file), I import it in the xml for the activity X.

Here is my toolbar in one single xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerChooser"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/new_gradients"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ChoosingActivity">
    <!--tools:openDrawer="start"-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

EDIT, new toolbar:

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@drawable/new_gradients"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/new_gradients"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".ChoosingActivity">


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my activity X:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class ChoosingActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private DrawerLayout drawer;



    public void userChoosed(View view) {


        Intent choosedIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(choosedIntent);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choosing);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbarxml);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawerChooser);

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        // Item will be Selected
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_meetings:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Ausstehende_Treffen_Fragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_finished_meetings:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Abgeschlossene_Treffen_Fragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_rate:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Treffen_Bewerten_Fragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_edit_profile:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Profil_Bearbeiten_Fragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_settings:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Einstellungen_Fragment()).commit();
                break;
        }

        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT, new activity X ( look at my comment "Toolbar_chooser or toolbar"):

```
public class ChoosingActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private DrawerLayout drawer;



    public void userChoosed(View view) {


        Intent choosedIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(choosedIntent);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choosing);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_chooser); // Toolbar_chooser or toolbar?
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawerChooser);

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        // Item will be Selected
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_meetings:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container_toolbar, new Ausstehende_Treffen_Fragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_finished_meetings:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container_toolbar, new Abgeschlossene_Treffen_Fragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_rate:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container_toolbar, new Treffen_Bewerten_Fragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_edit_profile:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container_toolbar, new Profil_Bearbeiten_Fragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_settings:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container_toolbar, new Einstellungen_Fragment()).commit();
                break;
        }

        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

And here my Fragment where I want to add the toolbar with the navigation view:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Ausstehende_Treffen_Fragment extends Fragment {


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ausstehende_treffen,container,false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar(toolbar); // HOW???

    }
}
```

EDIT, new Fragment:

```
public class Ausstehende_Treffen_Fragment extends Fragment {

   // Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbarreal);


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ausstehende_treffen,container,false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Toolbar toolbar = ((ChoosingActivity)getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.toolbar_ausstehende_treffen);

    }
}
```

Here is also my xml for the fragment, where I want to have the toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_ausstehende_treffen"
        layout= "@layout/toolbar"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ausstehende Treffen Fragment"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Im not able anymore to open my navigation bar in my choosing activity and I don't know why..

I include the toolbars manually in the xml files, its necessary right? + some code in the fragment itself. Man I hope you understand my code and my problems. Pls help me I just want to keep my custom toolbar in any fragment and activity.

Pls help me, its so frustrating, waste so many hours for just a toolbar, which already exists..

Comment: So you just want your Toolbar from your Activity to be visible in your Fragment?

Comment: Yes, my own one, which is also visible in my activity

Answer (score 0):

Try adding toolbar in you activity :

```
    mTopToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mTopToolbar);
```

Get the Activity that owns the fragment (Fragment.getActivity()) and set its ActionBar property.

Then juse use the same setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled method you mentioned to begin with on the ActionBar after setting your toolbar as the ActionBar to get the back / up button.

sample to access it from fragment :

```
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think he already did exactly what you are suggesting. And if he wants to persist the Toolbar throughout the application he doesn't have to go through all this trouble I think.

Comment: I want to display my custom toolbar in my whole application except one activity( start actitivty ).

Answer (score 0):

As simple as this.

```
Toolbar toolbar = ((ChoosingActivity)getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
```

Now do whatever you want to do man ;).

Comment: Where do I have to copy that? I saw this line so many times, it will not work for me. Pls tell me what I have to change.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because your `Toolbar` is covered by everything else in `DrawerLayout`. Try swapping `LinearLayout` and `DrawerLayout`, so that the vertical `LinearLayout` is your root layout, something like this:

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawerChooser"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/new_gradients"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ChoosingActivity">


    <FrameLayout
     android:id="@+id/fragment_container_toolbar"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu">

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Something approximately like that, the key is that your `Toolbar` has to be outside your `DrawerLayout`.

Comment: I changed my toolbar xml like this, I changed Drawer Layout on the top with Linear Layout. After that I still needed the Linear Layout, otherwise there is nothing showed. But There is still no custum toolbar with navigation drawer on my fragment. Is my code in my fragment correct?

Comment: @M.Hallweger Instead of wrapping your `Toolbar` in `LinearLayout` instead try wrapping it in `AppBarLayout`. Edit your question and put the new XML, I'll try to recreate the problem.

Comment: I added some new code. Pls tell me if you need some more. Here are also some strings for the closing and opening: <resources>
    <string name="app_name">Navigation Drawer Example</string>

    <string name="navigation_drawer_open">Open navigation drawer</string>
    <string name="navigation_drawer_close">Close navigation drawer</string>
</resources>

Comment: @M.Hallweger thanks for the code :) it's a bit time consuming to recreate the problem, but, I did a small research and found a [tutorial](http://mateoj.com/2015/06/21/adding-toolbar-and-navigation-drawer-all-activities-android/) that uses the same layout as you were using in the beginning, but the `FrameLayout` is inside the `LinearLayout`, try that, and try to compare it with yours, and then tell me how it goes

Comment: thanks but I need to keep my old version of the xml, otherwise Im not able to keep all on the right position and cannot click on the navigation drawer symbol. I think there is something wrong with the code in my fragment.

Comment: `public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Toolbar toolbar = ((ChoosingActivity)getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.toolbar_ausstehende_treffen);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar(toolbar);`

    Its the same like the above version, just changed it with the answer from @Khemraj

Comment: @M.Hallweger this line basically gives you control over your `Toolbar` in your `Fragment`, so after this line, you can modify the `Toolbar` using `toolbar.setVisibility` for example.